# How does Google Calendar send click from email WITHOUT loading a page?

Tags: html-email

I'd love to be able to do things like send a Poll via email and let people respond by just clicking WITHOUT needing to load a web page.

I thought that was impossible since (AFAIK) you can't use .js in email.

BUT... Google Calendar does this. Perhaps it only works in Gmail?

But if it *is* possible, I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 0):

You could create each answer in the poll as a link to a different page (or different redirect to the same page). Track how many hits each answer gets. Send the user to a "Thank you!" page after they click.